# Show list items based on date - Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, sqflite, flutter-listview, flutter-futurebuilder

I want to have a list when the date of each list item is equal to todays date.
I, personally, wrote this code in listview.builder in future builder:

```
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var now = DateTime.now();
            var nowFormated = DateFormat.MMMd().format(now);
            DateTime time = DateTime.parse(snapshot.data[index].date);
            var databaseFormated = DateFormat.MMMd().add_Hm().format(time);
            var checkerFormated = DateFormat.MMMd().format(time);
            if (checkerFormated == nowFormated) {
              print (checkerFormated);
              print(nowFormated);
              return Todays(
                  snapshot.data[index].name != null
                      ? snapshot.data[index].name
                      : '',
                  databaseFormated);
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          }
```

this code only works for the first item. it doesn't show any further items.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  final now = DateTime.now();
  final time = DateTime.parse(snapshot.data[index].date);
  final databaseFormated = DateFormat.MMMd().add_Hm().format(time);
  return (now.year == time.year && now.month == time.month && now.day == time.day) ? Todays(snapshot.data[index].name != null ? snapshot.data[index].name : '', databaseFormated) : SizedBox();
}
```

Comment: again, it just worked for the first item only.

Comment: I checked again; as long as i don't insert item that has a different date, it works, but when I have an item that has e.g tomorrow's date, nothing after that is shown.

Comment: But you clearly mentionned in your question `I want to have a list when the date of each list item is equal to todays date`

Comment: yes but it doesn't show with neither your and mine codes. it stops the list whenever i add an item with another date than today's date.

Comment: Post the full code of either your ListView or your full page

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. the problem was with the else return type was null. I gave it an empty sizedbox and it works.

```
else {
                      return SizedBox.shrink();
                    }
```